# How to add data to datagridview row by row

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

I am selecting a row from database. I want to add that row to a datagridview which has 3 columns in that row. I want to add those 3 columns to 3 rows.Can anyone can help? thanks!

this is my query

```
fillGrid("select selPriceCash1 as [Price 01] ,selPriceCash2 as [Price 02] ,selPriceCash3 as [Price 03] from tblItemInfo where code='" + itCode + "'");
```

And my code

```
 private void fillGrid(string selectCmd)
    {

        try
        {

            BindingSource b = new BindingSource();
            DataTable dt = cMethos.selectAtable(selectCmd);

            b.DataSource = dt;
            dgSend.DataSource = dt;
            if (dt.Rows.Count < 0)
            {
                dgSend.Rows[0].Cells[0].Selected = true;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception es)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(es.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: right at the first look, the only wrong thing in your code is the condition `dt.Rows.Count < 0`, however the data should be shown correctly as long as the `.selectAtable` method returns some non-empty dataTable.

Comment: This code is working correctly but as a one row and 3 columns. i want to show this data as a one column and 3 rows in a datadridview

Comment: you can have a table structure in you item template, or can look into repeater for greater degree of control

Answer (score 0):

Not the prettiest but should work

```
private void fillGrid(string selectCmd)
{
  List<string> Results = new List<string>();
  DataTable dt = cMethos.selectAtable(selectCmd);

  foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows())
  {
     foreach (object rowObject in row.ItemArray)
     {
         Results.Add(rowObject.ToString());
     }

  }

  dgSend.DataSource = Results;


}
```